# window.openDatabase() not working in phonegap javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to store files into a database using phonegap. I am getting an error that the window object does not support openDatabase. Can anyone give me a solution? All the documents I have read give the same syntax. Where am I going wrong?

```
storeInDB : function(csvBucketArr){
    db = window.openDatabase("testDB" , "1.0", "testDB", 1000000);
    db.transaction(app.setUp, app.errorHandler, app.dbReady);

    console.log("DB ready!!");
},

setUp: function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("create table if not exists fileLog(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, fileName TEXT UNIQUE, bucketName TEXT NOT NULL)");
},

errorHandler: function(e){
    alert("ERROR :: " + e.message);
},

dbReady: function(csvBucketArr){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        for(var i in csvBucketArr){
            var fname = csvBucketArr[i].fileKey, bname = csvBucketsArr[i].bucketName;
            tx.executeSql("insert into fileLog( fileName , bucketName) values (?,?)", [fname, bname]);
            alert("In dbReady");
        }
    }, errorHandler, function(){alert("files added to the table");});
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that you are calling storeInDB method after deviceready method(not document.ready)

Comment: yes. it is called after the deviceready method. i don't have a document.ready in my code

Comment: Maybe updating the phonegap library will help

Comment: I am working on phonegap 3.0